# How do I add values to a result column based on presence of certain specific values in another column in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following Customer Table

```
CUSTOMER_ID | Contact_Date| Score | GroupName  | GroupFactor |
------------+-------------+-------+------------+-----------------
100         | 2014-12-12  | 2     | elite      | .5
100         | 2014-12-10  | 82    | gold       | .25
100         | 2014-11-12  | 17    | elite      | .35
100         | 2014-10-12  | 85    | silver     | .45
100         | 2014-07-12  | 20    | elite      | .65
100         | 2015-06-12  | 2     | elite      | .5
100         | 2015-02-12  | 2     | elite      | .5
200         | 2014-12-12  | 200   | superelite | .95
200         | 2014-12-12  | 200   | superelite | .95
200         | 2014-12-12  | 200   | superelite | .95
```

Along with the table I have the following Information

- SCORE IN (2) AND SCORE IN (82, 83, 84) THEN .214
- SCORE IN (17, 18, 19) AND SCORE IN (85) THEN .182

Now, based on above information I want to write query which will

1. Check all the values in score column of Table 1 for Customer_ID per Year
2. If a customer has Score of 2 and any score of 82, 83, 84 a resultant score of .214 will be applied

Added SQLFIDDLE with Table 1 - 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9e4b/1

```
CUSTOMER_ID | Contact_Date| Score | GroupName  | GroupFactor | ResultantScore
------------+-------------+-------+------------+-----------------------------
100         | 2014-12-12  | 2     | elite      | .5          | .214
100         | 2014-12-10  | 82    | gold       | .25         | .00 (made 0 as .214 is already accounted for in Row 1) 
100         | 2014-11-12  | 17    | elite      | .35         | .182
100         | 2014-10-12  | 85    | silver     | .45         | .00(Similar to row 2)  
100         | 2014-07-12  | 20    | elite      | .65         | .65(Carried forward from GroupFactor as No Interaction is observed)
100         | 2015-06-12  | 2     | elite      | .5          | .5 (Considered again as year is 2015)
100         | 2015-02-12  | 2     | elite      | .5          | .00 
200         | 2014-12-12  | 200   | superelite | .95         | .95
200         | 2014-12-12  | 200   | superelite | .95         | .00
200         | 2014-12-12  | 200   | superelite | .95         | .00
```

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server or both decide

Comment: So you don't want the result grouped by year (of contact date) - you want to calculate ResultantScore by year but then apply it to the original data, for the earliest Contact_Date for each CUSTOMER_ID?

Comment: @Nathan - The Resultant Score should be grouped by Year of  'Contact date'. It's just that I don't want the same resultantscore to be repeated twice per CustomerID per Year

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that implements your first business rule (If a customer has Score of 2 and any score of 82, 83, 84 a resultant score of .214 will be applied):

```
SELECT 
  cs.*, 
  ScoreYearFlags.score_82_83_84, 
  FirstDateForScore2.FirstScoreDate, 
  CASE 
    WHEN cs.Score = 2 AND ScoreYearFlags.score_82_83_84 > 0 AND FirstDateForScore2.FirstScoreDate IS NOT NULL
       THEN 0.214
    WHEN cs.Score IN (82, 83, 84) THEN 0.00
    ELSE cs.GroupFactor
   END AS ResultantScore
FROM CustomerScore cs
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
    Customer_ID, 
    YEAR(Contact_Date) ContactYear,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Score IN(82,83,84) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS score_82_83_84
  FROM CustomerScore
  GROUP BY 
    Customer_ID, 
    YEAR(Contact_Date)
  ) ScoreYearFlags ON cs.Customer_ID = ScoreYearFlags.Customer_ID AND YEAR(cs.Contact_Date) = ScoreYearFlags.ContactYear
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
  SELECT Customer_ID,YEAR(Contact_Date) as ContactYear, Score, MIN(Contact_Date) AS FirstScoreDate
  FROM CustomerScore
  WHERE Score = 2
  GROUP BY Customer_ID, YEAR(Contact_Date), Score
 ) FirstDateForScore2 ON cs.Customer_ID = FirstDateForScore2.Customer_ID AND  
      YEAR(cs.Contact_Date) = FirstDateForScore2.ContactYear AND
      cs.Score = FirstDateForScore2.Score AND
      cs.Contact_Date = FirstDateForScore2.FirstScoreDate
```

I've had to make some assumptions e.g. it looks like you want ResultantScore to default to GroupFactor unless the score is "2" and the business rule applies, or the score is 82, 83 or 84 and then you want the ResultantScore to be 0.00.

This is a fairly complicated requirement for a single query, so I recommend you first write down the characteristics of the data you are expecting and all the business rules that will apply - this will help you get the logic in the query right. For example, what happens if a score 82 occurs *before* a score 2 in a single year - is the ResultantScore 0.00 or the GroupFactor? Perhaps this can never occur in your data, but this is the sort of thing you need to consider.

Comment: I will compile a list of all rules and send it over. I will need to do additional research so may take a while. Thank you so much for helping me out.